# Using rule output as function

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, rule, difference-equations

Im trying to define a function using the output from RSolve, however i cant get it to work properly.

I have a RSolve that output something like:

```
BK[n] -> 2n + 5
```

and now i would like to define a function that has that property like:

```
BK[n_] := 2n + 5
```

so that when i do for instance:

```
BK[4]
```

i'll get 13.
Is there a way to use this rule and define it as a function as proposed above?
Note that the rule is far more complicated than what i gave as an example so that's why i dont want to simply copy the output as it is.

Comment: What you are asking can be done. But the better solution would be to `RSolve` for `BK` instead of `BK[n]`, because that would give you a pure function which can be used directly.

Comment: Right... and never use upper-case letters for your functions, as they might conflict with the internal functions of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RSolveValue[eqn,a,n]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolveValue.html) the result of which is a pure function that can be used as is without any further processing:

```
ClearAll[bK]
bK = RSolveValue[a[n + 1] - 2 a[n] == 1, a, n];
bK[2]
```

> 3 + 2 C[1]

**Update:** For multiple functions:

```
ClearAll[bk, ff, if]
eq1 = bk[n + 1] == 0.9 bk[n] + 0.25 ff[n] + 0.2 if[n];
eq2 = ff[n + 1] == 0.05 bk[n] + 0.7 ff[n] + 0.2 if[n];
eq3 = if[n + 1] == 0.05 bk[n] + 0.05 ff[n] + 0.6 if[n];
{bkF, ffF, ifF} = RSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, eq3, bk[0] == 2000, ff[0] == 1000, 
    if[0] == 2000}, {bk, ff, if}, n];

bkF[2]
```

> 2775.

```
ffF[3]
```

> 1200.

```
ifF[5]
```

> 628.252

Comment: Great! Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that for your ultimate goal, you should consider other use cases of RSolveValue.. But I wanted to, for fun, add an answer to the question "use rule to define function", and I wonder if anybody else has any nifty answers to this as well.. Here's one I came up with:

```
In[6]:= 

setRuleDelayed[Rule[lhs_, rhs_]] := 
Quiet[
    (Evaluate[Replace[lhs, (val_ :> val_), {1}]] := rhs)
    , 
    RuleDelayed::rhs
]
setRuleDelayed[BK[n] -> 2 n + 5]
DownValues[BK]

Out[8]= {HoldPattern[BK[n_]] :> 5 + 2 n}

In[9]:= BK[4]

Out[9]= 13
```

Answer (score 0):

RSolveValue seems to be working for just one function however this is the case:

```
eq1 = bk[n+1] == 0.9 bk[n] + 0.25 ff[n] + 0.2 if[n];
eq2 = ff[n+1] == 0.05 bk[n] + 0.7 ff[n] + 0.2 if[n];
eq3 = if[n+1] == 0.05 bk[n] + 0.05 ff[n] + 0.6 if[n];
sol= RSolve[{eq1,eq2,eq3,bk[0] == 2000,ff[0] == 1000,if[0] == 2000 },{bk[n],ff[n],if[n]},n] //First //FullSimplify
```

To clarify; I would like each separate functions (bk,ff,if) to be defined as function that I can use.
i.e bk[2] = something, ff[3] = something else

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oscar, please see the update in my answer.